# How to Speed Up VBA from Excel to PPt

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I am using VBA in excel to create a daily report in PPt by copying and pasting pictures and ranges. it works really well but is a little slow. any suggestions?

I already have:

```
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
    .DisplayAlerts = False
End With
```

Suggestions?

Comment: Without seeing your code, it would be hard to suggest improvements.  But if your code is working, it would possibly be better to post it at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

A few things to consider:

1. Copy and paste (pictures, ranges, charts, etc) works faster if made as picture instead for example embedding object from Excel in PPT
2. If possible source data used to build the PPT slides should be placed/ kept inside PPT
3. Running the show from Excel might be considerably slower compared to placing the code in a PPT module (if this is applicable)
   Here is a nice
4. Newer versions of Excel/PPT appear to perform slower compared to older ones. If your data is not outside the number of rows that can hold a sheet of Excel 2003, it might worth it to give it a try.

Good luck!